# What do all these parameters when calling a WCF web method from Anguilla JavaScript mean?

Tags: tridion

I have the following (from [Tridion PowerTools](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/)), which gets a user name from the CoreService when some JavaScript runs.

**JavaScript (Anguilla):**

```
PowerTools.Popups.Example.prototype._onbtnGetUserInfoClicked = function () { 
    var onSuccess = Function.getDelegate(this, this._handleUserInfo);
    var onFailure = null;
    var context = null;
    //call function
    PowerTools.Model.Services.Example.GetUserInfo(onSuccess, onFailure, 
                                                  context, false);
}; 

// Delegate function "onSuccess"
PowerTools.Popups.Example.prototype._handleUserInfo = function (response) {
    var p = this.properties;
    $j("#lblUserInfo").text(response.UserName);
};
```

**CoreService side: (C# .svc)**

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public ExampleData GetUserInfo()
{
    var coreService = Client.GetCoreService();
    _exampleData = new ExampleData()
    {
        UserName = coreService.GetCurrentUser().Title
    };
    return _exampleData;
}
```

This sends an asynchronous call:

`PowerTools.Model.Services.Example.GetUserInfo(onSuccess, onFailure, context, false)`

Whereas this assigns a different function to handle the response:

`Function.getDelegate(this, this._handleUserInfo)`

But where does onSuccess, onFailure, context, and the Boolean come from in: **`PowerTools.Model.Services.Example.GetUserInfo(onSuccess, onFailure, context, false)`**?

This four-parameter signature doesn't match the no-paramater GetUserInfo() in the service code. Why that order and these four?

Comment: Edit: clarified which part I was confused about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `onSuccess` and `onFailure` are the callback functions that are assigned for handling the response from the WCF service.

Assuming this is code from the PowerTools project, there is an auto-generated JavaScript method that acts as a proxy method for a WCF service (source of the service is [here](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Model/Services/Example.svc.cs)) method called `GetUserInfo()`.

In there you can actually see the call to the CoreService. That should explain to you the mapping of the proxy parameters.

1. `onSuccess` is the function to process the response of the WCF service
2. `onFailure` is the function to run if the call fails
3. `context` is a variable that will be passed back into your callback functions, so you can use it to pass things around.
4. `false` is whether the call is synchronous or not

If your WCF service were to take parameters, the generated proxy would form a different signature, something like

```
PowerTools.Model.Services.Example.GetOtherInfo(param1, param2, onSuccess, 
                                               onFailure, context, false);
```

Comment: So if the C# function is successful, your onSuccess will be called with the return value from the C# function. 
If there is a failure, your onFailure will be called (with the exception I think). 
And either of those callbacks will also get the userContext you pass in.

Comment: The explanation and example with additional parameters really helps, thanks! We get onSuccess, onFailure, context, and the synchronous boolean "for free" with the WCM service, which are then available to be (optionally) set as as delegates.