# How to GetLocalizedItems using Tridion Anguilla Framework?

Tags: tridion

I would like to use the GetLocalizedItems method in the Anguilla Framework.

I don't know how to create a new filter and set the conditions or what to use for success and failure.

In the GUI:

```js
tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WhereUsed.GetListUsedItems(id, filter.conditions, 
    filter.columns, success, failure);
```

Are the methods in this namespace intended to be used by our extensions?

Comment: Hey Robert. I don't know for sure if they are in the public API (I'll check), but they are definitely used quite often. Check this question and the answer on the meaning of those parameters: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385892/what-do-all-these-parameters-when-calling-a-wcf-web-method-from-anguilla-javascr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Building a filter

Here is an example of how to build a filter

```js
var filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
filter.conditions.ItemTypes = 16 | 2; // folders and components
filter.conditions.Recursive = true;
filter.conditions.BasedOnSchema = "tcm:1-23-8,tcm:1-32-8".split(",");
filter.columns = Tridion.Constants.ColumnFilter.DEFAULT;
```

Or this extremely simple case from General.js:

```js
var templateFilter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter({ 
    conditions: { ItemTypes: [ itemType ] } 
});
```

---

### Calling a WCF method

The second part of your question was really already covered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9385975/209103, although I'll make it a bit more concrete here.

WCF/AJAX calls such as this are executed asynchronously, since they may take some time to complete. While you would normally simple handle the result of the call on the line after the closing parenthesis, you can't do that in AJAX calls since that line will be execute before the function has completed. Instead you have to pass in one or more callback functions that get called once the function completes.

I typically just pass in two functions that break into the JavaScript debugger of my browser when I first start figuring out such a method:

```js
Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WhereUsed.GetListUsedItems(
    "tcm:1-23", 
    filter.conditions, 
    filter.columns, 
    new function() { console.log(arguments); debugger; }, 
    new function() { console.log(arguments); debugger; }
);
```

So the first (anonymous) function is called when the (asynchronous) HTTP call to the TCM server succeeded, while the second is called when the call failed. In the answer I linked above, we called them `onSuccess` and `onFailure` to make their nature more explicit.

Both functions in this case simply write the implicit `arguments` parameter that is always passed in JavaScript. They then break into the JavaScript debugger of your browser, so you can inspect the arguments further.

Comment: I was referring the Anguilla Framework documentation, and when I tried to looked at the Listfilter properties, I could find conditions but none of the other properties, like "ItemTypes", "Recursive". Can you help me where to look for them

Comment: I normally just do a search on the Anguilla code. It's all non-obfuscated JavaScript, so you can find an "example" of anything that the GUI does in it.

Comment: Any particular folder that you search, or you meant the documentation.

Comment: No, I meant the Anguilla **code**. Just do a search (with a search tool that searches **inside** files) for ListFilter on your %TRIDION_HOME% directory and see what it shows up.